# Taxonomy-term based block display

Tags: taxonomy-terms, blocks, panels

I'm trying to display certain blocks in taxonomy term pages and the nodes associated based on the taxonomy term itself.

Let's say I have 3 taxonomy terms: Bologna, Milan and Rome.

When I'm in Bologna taxonomy-term page I would like to display a block that show the map of Bologna, when I'm in Milan taxonomy-term page the Milan map and so on.

Context module seems to work with node associated to a particular taxonomy term (for example, I'm able to display Milan map block in every node associated with Milan taxonomy term), but doesn't work for the taxonomy page itself.

I think the trick is in Panels.
I've enabled the taxonomy-term page override but I do not know how to display blocks based on arguments.

I've used views and panels many times before but never faced this particular problem: It's a bit different that filtering with arguments particular nodes or content types.

Answer (score 0):

Kropot,

Have you tried views contextual filters?

1. Create a block view.
2. Add a Contextual filters with Content: Has taxonomy term ID.
3. defalt value: Taxonomy Term ID from URL
4. Add the fields to display.
5. Add the filters.

Deepak

Comment: Thank you for the answer @deepak-ml 
This works when you have to display a particular content based on taxonomy term ID. But how to do that when you want to display particular **blocks** based on taxonomy term?
Block_A in taxonomy_term_A page, Block_B in taxonomy_term_B page, and so on (using Panels).

Comment: how are the different blocks Block_A Block_B etc are related to the terms ?

Comment: This is exactly the problem :) How to relate blocks with the terms? 
There is a similar question [here](http://drupal.org/node/1167442)  
I wasn't able to find a solution using [Context](http://drupal.org/project/context) module  
The [block_term](http://drupal.org/project/block_term) module seems to be in alpha state and it doesn't mention integrations with views.

Comment: With a content type eg. relative_block with fields image and taxonomy reference ( same vocabulary as actual content type ) and actual content type where you  reference the term. The views block will display the image field associated with that term.

Comment: Yep, I was thinking at the same workaround: in my case, creating a content type called "Map" using the same vocabulary, create the content Map_A, Map_B and Map_C, then a views content pane wich displays only the body field, and then configure as usual Contextual filters and arguments in panels. Maybe we can write down a workaround :)

Comment: It's not a workaround to me, it's the correct way to do this. Creating new block for each map is pretty like creating new bloc for each article isn't it?. It's even a better way to link the map by a "entity reference" field directly on the taxonomy.